# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So I'm doing a tutorial on Skillshare for building a microblog. As part of the github login he instructed to build a function that has a axios post. and whenever i call this route it gives me an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')" at line 12, which is the below variable. I cant seem to figure out what's wrong. any idea why its giving me this error?

```
const githubAuthResult = await axios.post(
    `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=${environment.clientId}&client_secret=${environment.clientSecret}&code=${code}`,
    null,
    { headers: { Accept: 'application.json' } }
  );
```

yes i have the axios and the environment variables import

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

The full code of the route if needed can be found [here](https://github.com/cwilliamson29/microblog/blob/main/apps/api/src/app/routes/Auth.ts)

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your axios version: 1.1.3 has some
[issues](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5011)
Downgrading to 1.1.0 should help you move on

Comment: Your answer is correct but there is a bit more to it than downgrading, i have added an exomplanation of this in my question for anyone needing it